A different approach to Nakayama's lemma.
I'm studying "Algebras, Rings and Modules Vol.1".
Prosposition 3.4.9 says,

$\mathbf{Proposition\  3.4.9}.$ Let $M$ be a right $A$-module, and let $R$ be the radical of the ring $A$. Then $MR\subset 
 radM.$

and the radical of a module $M$ is at first defined as the intersection of all (proper) maximal submodules of $M$.
Then follows the Nakayama lemma:

$\mathbf{Lemma\ 3.4.11\ (Nakayama\text{'}s\ Lemma).}$ Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module and $MR=M$. Then $M=0$.

In the spirit of Prosposition 3.4.9, I'd like to proceed as
$$M=MR\subset rad M=\bigcap\{N:N\subset M \text{ is a maximal submodule of M}\}$$
It is clear that $M$ has no maximal submodules.
Is it possible to conclude that $M=0$ from the assumption that $M$ is finitely generated?
Does every nontrivial f.g. module has a maximal submodule? Do we need the Axiom of Choice?

The duplicate was found by using site search for 1min.
